# How to parse json.response dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to parse the following dictionary received json response and am running into issues. My dictionary name is results.

This is a simple json response that appears to be dict.

```
{'resultType': 'vector', 'result': [{'metric': {'agent_host': 'x.x.x.x', 'cluster_name': 'test_cluser', 'device_type': 'switch', 'hostname': 'myswitch', 'ifName': 'xe-0/0/10', 'instance': 'telegraf:1111', 'job': 'telegraf', 'rack_name': 'test_rack', 'site_name': 'test_site'}, 'value': [1631917506.324, '0.00009262475396549728']}]}
```

Type confirms that:

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Ultimately what I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
for key, value in results.items():
    (rx_error, rx_error_freq) = value[16]
```

In order to get the value 0.00009262475396549728 from above. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What were you expecting `value[16]` to get?

Answer (score -1):

One great way to visualize nested dictionaries is to use `pprint` which comes built into python3

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {'resultType': 'vector', 'result': [{'metric': {'agent_host': 
    'x.x.x.x', 'cluster_name': 'test_cluser', 'device_type': 'switch', 
    'hostname': 'myswitch', 'ifName': 'xe-0/0/10', 'instance': 
    'telegraf:1111', 'job': 'telegraf', 'rack_name': 'test_rack', 
    'site_name': 'test_site'}, 'value': [1631917506.324, 
    '0.00009262475396549728']}]}


pprint(d)
>>> {'result': [{'metric': {'agent_host': 'x.x.x.x',
                            'cluster_name': 'test_cluser',
                            'device_type': 'switch',
                            'hostname': 'myswitch',
                            'ifName': 'xe-0/0/10',
                            'instance': 'telegraf:1111',
                            'job': 'telegraf',
                            'rack_name': 'test_rack',
                            'site_name': 'test_site'},
                'value': [1631917506.324, '0.00009262475396549728']}],
     'resultType': 'vector'}
```

This allows us to see the different key value pairs a lot more easily. So the data you're looking to access would is

```
rx_error, rx_error_freq = d["result"][0]["value"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Loop over the `result` list to get the `value`, then print the second element

```
>>> data = {'resultType': 'vector', 'result': [{'metric': {'agent_host': 'x.x.x.x', 'cluster_name': 'test_cluser', 'device_type': 'switch', 'hostname': 'myswitch', 'ifName': 'xe-0/0/10', 'instance': 'telegraf:1111', 'job': 'telegraf', 'rack_name': 'test_rack', 'site_name': 'test_site'}, 'value': [1631917506.324, '0.00009262475396549728']}]} 
>>> for r in data['result']:
...   print(r['value'][1])
...
0.00009262475396549728
```

Comment: Thanks! I just run into this type error though:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You didn't include much code in your question, but see my update